# Kunneth and Dold-Thom

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, higher-homotopy-groups

Let $X$ and $Y$ be connected CW complexes. By Kunneth's theorem we have a map of the form $H_i(X)\times H_j(Y) \rightarrow H_{i+j}(X\times Y)$. By Dold-Thom this translates to a map of homotopy groups of the following form (whenever $i,j>0$ since Dold-Thom is an isomorphism between the homotopy groups and reduced homology):
$$\pi_i(SP(X))\times \pi_j(SP(Y))\rightarrow \pi_{i+j}(SP(X\times Y))$$

Here $SP$ denotes the infinite symmetric product. I was wondering whether there is an explicit map $SP(X)\wedge SP(Y)\rightarrow SP(X\wedge Y)$ such that passing to the homotopy groups the following map is the same as the Kunneth map?

$$\pi_i(SP(X))\times \pi_j(SP(Y))\rightarrow \pi_{i+j}(SP(X)\wedge SP(Y))\rightarrow \pi_{i+j}(SP(X\wedge Y)) \rightarrow  \pi_{i+j}(SP(X\times Y))$$

Note that there is an obvious map $SP(X)\wedge SP(Y)\rightarrow SP(X\wedge Y)$ which seems should be the answer, I am looking for a proof. The obvious map is given by taking pairwise points and pairing them and considering them as a point in $X\times Y$. then looking at its image in $X\wedge Y$.

Comment: Well there is an obvious "tensor product" map $SP(X)\wedge SP(Y)\to SP(X\times Y)$ which sends $(\sum x_i,\sum y_j)$ to $\sum_{i,j}(x_i, y_j)$.  This is surely the map you want, though it would take some work to prove it.

Comment: @EricWofsey That is what I was suspecting but I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: @EricWofsey There is also another problem that, the product you are defining is actual product that does not give a smash product. So probably this is not it. If this did descend to a smash product then fixing the base point in $SP(X)$ and pairing it with $SP(Y)$ should go to the base point in $SP(X\times Y)$. This doesn't happen.

Comment: That's not a problem: $SP(X)$ is the free commutative monoid on $X\setminus\{x_0\}$ where $x_0$ is the basepoint, with the basepoint becoming $0$.

Comment: @EricWofsey There is a map $SP(X)\wedge SP(Y) \rightarrow SP(X\wedge Y)$ and there is a similar map when $\wedge$ is replaced by $\times$. But there isn't map from $\wedge$ to $\times$. Althought you can define a map at the homology level $H_i(SP(X\wedge Y))\rightarrow H_i(SP(X\times Y))$ (split injection by Kunneth decomposition), which helps to get the map you are talking about. But there is another problem with it, if $i$ or $j$ is zero, then although the map on homologies is non-zero but the one on the homotopies seems to be zero.

Comment: By the way homology in the third line in the comment above should be homotopy.

Comment: NVM this actually not problem since dold thom gives the isomorphism between homotopy groups and reduced homology. This looks fine just needs a proof.

Comment: Isn't Dold-Thom a statement about reduced homology? e.g your external product should be $\widetilde H^*X\otimes \widetilde H^*Y\rightarrow\widetilde H^*(X\wedge Y)$.

Comment: @Tyrone Yes, that is what my last comment is about.

Comment: Well, then the correct t translation of the external product to a map of homotopy groups of the form $\pi_i(Sp(X))\otimes \pi_j(Sp(Y))\rightarrow\pi_{i+j}(Sp(X\wedge Y))$. Thus you should be asking for a map $Sp(X)\wedge Sp(Y)\rightarrow Sp(X\wedge Y)$. Eric's suggestion seems to work for this.

Comment: @Tyrone That is what I am asking (after the comment section), what Eric suggests i e. the most obvious thing you can do, can work. The only problem is a proof.

Comment: It might be a good idea to edit your question if you know it is formulated incorrectly.